# Are these two definitions of smooth $k$-manifold as a Euclidean subset equivalent?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am struggling to reconcile the two definitions of smooth k-manifold in $R^n$ from M.Spivaks **Calculus on Manifolds** (pg 109) and J.W Minor's **Topology from differential point of view** (pg 01).

***Milnor's Definition***

The key concept in Milnor's definition is ***smooth*** function, between ***arbitrary*** subsets of Euclidean space.
If $f:X \to Y$ and $X \subset R^n, Y\subset R^m$. Then $f$ is ***smooth*** if for each point $p \in X$, there is a an open neighbourhood $U \subset R^n$ and a $C^\infty$ function $F:U \to V$ ($V \subset R^m$ is open) that is compatible (an extension of) with $f$. i.e, $F_{|X \cap U} = f_{|X \cap U}$. Now the ***diffeomorphism*** between subsets becomes smooth function that has a ***two-sided*** inverse which is also smooth.

The definition of a ***k-manifold*** is now made quite naturally as a subset of $R^n$ which is ***diffeomorphic*** to an open subset in $R^k$.

***Spivak's Definition.***

Spivak only considers invertible (having two-sided inverse) $C^\infty$ function between ***open*** subsets and calls this a ***diffeomorphism***, of course this agrees with Milnor's definition when $X, Y$ above are open subsets. Then Spivak's defines the ***smooth k-manifold*** using this diffeomorphism. A subset $M\in R^n$ is a ***k-manifold*** if the following criteria are satisfied.

- For any $p \in M$, there is an open neighbourhood of $p$, $U\subset R^n$ and a ***diffeomorphism***, $f:U \to V$, $V$ open subset in $R^n$ satisfying,
- $f(M\cap U) = V \cap ( R^k \times \{0\} )$

---

***My thoughts***

I can see that "Spivak" $\implies $ "Milnor". But I don't find the other direction trivial. Assuming Milnor's definition holds, there is a function $f:M \to V$. Where $M$ is the manifold and $V$ is an open subset of $R^k$ and there is a two-sided inverse to this function $f^{-1}$. Since they are both ***smooth*** (according to the definition of Milnor), given a point $p \in M$, we can construct the following $C^\infty$ functions (that reduce to $f, f^{-1}$ where they are commonly defined), for an open neighbourhood $U \subset R^n$ of $p$ and an open set $V' \subset R^k$.

- $F:U \to V'$ ($V'$ open in $R^k$)
- $G:V' \to U$

Clearly, $F$ is not ***injective*** and $G$ is not ***onto*** in general ($n \neq k$). How can one build a $C^\infty$ invertible map that Spivak uses in his definition from these functions, i.e by extending the dimension of domain/range appropriately. I am quite puzzled. Perhaps, I am missing something very trivial. I will really appreciate any help since I am doing a self-study. Thanks in advance.

---

Milnor's Book: http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/Dispense/Milnor%20Topology%20from%20%23681EA.pdf

Spivak's Book:
http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/spivak-calc-manifolds.pdf

Comment: I don't have Milnor's book here, but I think it should have *locally* diffeomorphic (otherwise we miss e.g. closed curves)

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks for the comment. Here is a link to Milnor's book:
http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/Dispense/Milnor%20Topology%20from%20%23681EA.pdf. I am not quite sure what "locally" diffeomorphic is?

Comment: @PietroMajer Ah! I see what you mean _locally_ diffeomorphic. I think it is, it happens in the definition of smooth maps.

Comment: But any point has a nbd with its diffeo. Here (in both definitions) "locally diffeomorphic" refers to: Any point of $M$ has an open nbd $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and a diffeo  $\phi:U\to V$ onto another open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that flatten the trace of $M$ in $U$, that is $\phi(U\cap M)=V\cap E$, $E$ being a $k$-dimensional subspace. An equivalent definition would be: $M$ is locally a graph of a smooth function of $k$ variables (with value in the span of the other $n-k$, so that the graph is indeed a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$)